# Generic way to set property on dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a dynamic object.

I want to set a property to a value if the property exists

```
    private static void SetValue(ref dynamic property, object value)
    {
        if(property != null)
        { 
            property = value;
        }
    }
```

So this would be

```
SetValue(ref resource.name, "[parameters('name')]");
```

However, this approach doesnt work for dynamic as apparently you cant use ref for them

How can I implement this?  Im happy to use an extension method if thats the only way

Im setting quite a few properties that may or may not exist

Without a solution like this my code will be a mess because I will constantly need to be checking for null

```
 if (resource["name"] != null)
 { 
     resource["name"] = "Value etc";
 }
```

Paul

Comment: So it's like setting a value in a dictionary only if the key already exists?

Comment: kind of yeah, I am taking json and deserialiizing it into dynamic because the structure can change and I dont want to mimic it my side

Comment: this sounds like a terrible idea, honestly, and indeed that's not how `ref` works re properties; also: is `value` actually `dynamic`, or is that not necessary? i.e. would reflection suffice here?

Comment: So, how about deser'ing it to a dictionary and only writing new value for key `k` if `d.ContainsKey(k)`?

Comment: I doubt reflection would work on a dynamic object produced by json.net? It won't have actual properties/fields to reflect over, just magic done by `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`

Comment: It looks like you can assign an object of type `JObject` to `dynamic`, so why not do your manipulating on the `JObject`, then convert to `dynamic` later if you want to?

Comment: I cannot deserialize into JObject as I get an error with a json value I have no control over

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to add a check everywhere to see if a property exists before I set it

Comment: @Paul what is the error when you deserialize to `JObject`. Also you can deserialize to `JToken` if it is possible that you can get anything.

Comment: I managed to get it over to JObject thats fine now it turns out that behind the scenes it actually is a JObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static void UpdateValue<T, TProperty>(
        ref T thing,
        Func<T, TProperty> getter,
        Action<T, TProperty> setter,
        TProperty value)
    {
        if(getter(thing) != null)
        {
            setter(thing, value);
        }
    }
```

Can be called directly:

```
UpdateValue<Employee>(
    ref person,
    (p) => p.name,
    (p, name) => p.name = name,
    "John Smith");
```

Or with some helper wrappers:

```
private static void UpdateName(ref Employee person, string name)
{
    UpdateValue(
        ref person,
        (p) => p.name,
        (p, name) => p.name = name,
        name);

}

private static void UpdateDob(ref Employee person, DateTime dob)
{
    UpdateValue(
        ref person,
        (p) => p.DateOfBirth,
        (p) => p.DateOfBirth = dob,
        dob);
}
```